# Single interface for multiple email accounts

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange, imap, email-client

I have multiple e-mail accounts (about 10) and multiple devices I use to access mail from those accounts. It is very inconvenient to setup everything on each device and keep everything in sync.

Is there some way/service which will allow me to:

1. Setup everything in one place. Email accounts, sorting rules (like in Outlook), I have many rules.
2. Receive exact same mails organized in exact same way (hierarchic of folders, structure, read/unread status & etc) on all devices.

As I see it this could be a web service where I setup multiple e-mail accounts where it downloads e-mails and aggregates it into 1 virtual account.  The service would sort them by folders using my rules and then provides access to them via imitating IMAP (to provide folders and so that client software thought that it is usual mailbox). But when you reply, forward e-mail it knew which address to use to send e-mail.

Does someone know of a similar service? Does Exchange Server or Office 365 solves this in any way?

Comment: Does Outlook not permit this for the accounts you have?

Comment: Yes, I have everything perfectly setup on a single device, but it is painful to sync between 4 of my other PCs/Mac and other devices. I thought that maybe there is some kind of service or technology which allows to setup everything as in Outlook but then access results via simpler interface without any setup on the client.

Comment: If any of those accounts is on GMail or Google Apps, you can consolidate into it as Google very thorough filtering & labeling options.

Comment: AOL has a new e-mail client called Alto, maybe try giving that a shot. Not that familiar with it so here is a link http://venturebeat.com/2012/10/18/aol-alto-email-service/#s:alto_03_dealstack

Answer (score 0):

Paul Thurrott has written a lot of good stuff about various ways of consolidating different email accounts, in  [Thinking About Email Consolidation Strategies](http://www.winsupersite.com/article/cloud-computing2/thinking-email-consolidation-strategies-139982)

A good article to start with is  [Windows Phone 7.5: Linked Inbox For Email Consolidation](http://www.winsupersite.com/article/windowsphone75/windows-phone-75-linked-inbox-email-consolidation-141922). Although it is talking about using his setup on Windows Phone devices, it links to his earlier articles that give the background, and describe two different strategies:

- Collecting email from other accounts
- Forwarding email to other accounts

He covers these approaches in both Microsoft Hotmail and Google Gmail.